# Prove that if $\: \forall_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: \overline{\overline{A}}_t = c$ then $\overline{\overline{\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: A_t}} = c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

> Prove that if $\: \forall_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: \overline{\overline{A}}_t$ is equal to cardinality $c$, then $\:\overline{\overline{\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: A_t}}$ is also equal to cardinality $c$.

Here is my attempt:
If we know that $\: \forall_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: \overline{\overline{A}}_t$ then $\: \forall_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \exists_{f_t} \: f_t: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A_t $ and those fuctions are surjective.

Now we can make function $\: F: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: A_t$

$F(n, m) = f_n(m)$ which is also surjective.

Since we know that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is equal to cardinality then $\:\overline{\overline{\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \: A_t}}$ has also have to be equal to cardinality.

Is my proof done right?

Comment: It is not enough that the $f_t$ are surjective.

Comment: @Andres: One appeal to choice is already given here, this would be another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the axiom of choice to choose these functions, which is a particularly delicate point. Without the axiom of choice it is consistent, for example, that the union of countably many sets, each of size continuum, has cardinality strictly larger than the continuum.

If you assume the axiom of choice, and you have shown that if $A$ surjects onto $B$, and $A$ injects onto $B$, then $|A|=|B|$, then yes. This proof is correct.

If you haven't done that, you can either do that, or require that the $A_t$'s are pairwise disjoint and $f_t$ is actually a bijection, then show that $F$ is a bijection as well. Without the assumption on the $A_t$'s you need to do another round of choices, to reduce these sets a bit. Which makes it much easier to use the axiom of choice again, and show that from an injection and a surjection from $\Bbb R$, we get equicardinality.

Comment: So it is like: we know that if the set $|A| = c$ and $|B| = c$ then there exists bijection between $A$ and $B$. Since we know that can I assume that every $f_t$ is bijection then show that $F$ is bijection too?

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: But we can show that? Let say $F(x, m) = f_x(m) = y$ so there can be function $F(z, m) = f_z(m) = y$ so it is not injective. Is that correct?

Comment: Wait, do you assume that the $A_t$'s are pairwise disjoint? You are correct, if they are not pairwise disjoint then this function is not necessarily injective.

Comment: My knowledge about axiom of choice is very poor. Can you explain me just a bit how can 'assume' axiom of choice and how I can pick those function using it?

Comment: The fact that you move from "There exists a bijection" to "define $F$ as $F(z,m)=f_z(m)$" is exactly choosing such bijection. Since if there is one bijection between $A$ and $\Bbb R$, there are many many many bijections between $A$ and $R$, so which one do you take? *That* is the axiom of choice in action.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. I will try to improve my proof. Thanks.